# What is the difference between Spring and SpringBoot?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

Please Explain me the exact difference between the spring and spring boot?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/spring-boot/info, https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot

Comment: "Spring Boot makes it easy to create stand-alone, production-grade Spring based Applications that you can 'just run'" .. (so you can say  [tag:spring-boot] is a [tag:spring] "addon".)

Answer (score 0):

One clear explanation from [Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-vs-spring-boot)

**About Spring**

> Spring framework provides comprehensive infrastructure support for developing Java applications.

**About SpringBoot**

> Spring Boot is basically an extension of the Spring framework which eliminated the boilerplate configurations required for setting up a Spring application.

To resume, Spring is a framework and SpringBoot is a part of this framework to simplify and help you to configure a Spring application